# Search result direct to search result page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a simple search from MYSQL, it displays a single data from my table
"employee_id" it already has an link on output i want it to direct to another page with the same id and output the whole table from its called id

I already have the code to direct to another page but is displays all the data from my table

I am new on php and I am also a student

**form:**

```
<form action="searchemp.php?searchresult" method="post"> 
    <p id="srchlbl">Search by Employee ID:</p>
    <input id="srchtxt" type="text" name="employee_id" placeholder="Search for Employee..."><br>
    <input id="srchbttn" name="search" type="submit" value="search">
    <input name="viewall" type="submit" value="view all">
```

**search**

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{   if(isset($_GET['searchresult']))
    {       if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['employee_id']))
        {   $name = $_POST['employee_id'];
            $sql = "SELECT  * FROM employee WHERE employee_id LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'"; 
            $result=mysql_query($sql);



            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die($result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
            $e_id  = $row['employee_id']; 

            echo "<ul>\n"; 
            echo "<b>search results</b>";
            echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"singlesearchresult.php?action=employee_id\">".$e_id . "</a></li>\n"; 
            echo "</ul>"; 
        } 
    } 
        else{ 
            echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
             } 
}
```

**singlesearchresult**

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT employee_id, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_address, emp_email, emp_contact FROM employee';
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql);

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      echo      
                "<ul><li>EMPLOYEE ID : {$row['employee_id']}  <br> ".
                "EMPLOYEE NAME : {$row['emp_fname']} <br> ".
                "EMPLOYEE LASTNAME : {$row['emp_lname']} <br> ".
                "EMPLOYEE ADDRESS : {$row['emp_address']} <br> ".
                "EMPLOYEE EMAIL : {$row['emp_email']} <br> ".
                "EMPLOYEE CONACT : {$row['emp_contact']} <br> ".
                  "---------------------------------------------------------</li></ul>";

   }

   echo "<br><b>Fetched data successfully</b>\n";


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **search**

Use this:

```
echo "<li><a href='singlesearchresult.php?action=".$e_id."'>".$row['emp_fname']."</a></li>\n";
```

On **singlesearchresult** page:

```
<?php
$getEmpID = $_GET['action'];
$sql = "SELECT employee_id, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_address, emp_email, emp_contact FROM employee WHERE employee_id = '$getEmpID' ";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql);
... // rest of your code
?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['employee_id']` are you sure about that??

Comment: @Dagon opps.. i made the changes.. it should be `action`

Comment: unidentified variable .$emp_fname. on search 

and on singlesearchresult
Could not get data: Champ '$getEmpID' inconnu dans where clause

Comment: @JustAngelo ir should be `$row['emp_fname']`, check my updated answer

Comment: @Palhik Vejani sorry

still it gives me this 
Could not get data: Champ '$getEmpID' inconnu dans where clause

Comment: @JustAngelo what happend?

Comment: @Palhik Vejani i dont know sir, the search is correct but displaying data gives me this Could not get data: Champ '$getEmpID' inconnu dans where clause

Comment: @JustAngelo i have updated my query: `$sql = 'SELECT employee_id, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_address, emp_email, emp_contact FROM employee WHERE employee_id = '$getEmpID'';`

Comment: still the same result sir,

Comment: @JustAngelo try this: `$sql = "SELECT employee_id, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_address, emp_email, emp_contact FROM employee WHERE employee_id = '$getEmpID' ";`

Comment: @JustAngelo accept it so it is helpful to other users

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the id to use:

```
 echo '<li><a  href="singlesearchresult.php?id='.$e_id.'">'.$e_id.'</a></li>\n";
```

then on singlesearchresult.php use `$_GET['id']` in the query

```
$sql = 'SELECT employee_id, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_address, emp_email, emp_contact FROM employee WHERE employee_id="'.$_GET['id'].'"';
```

**NB:** this is just an example its crazy unsafe, you must sanatise the value passed in the url before using it in the query

Comment: hi, the code you give doesn't display the search result

Comment: your not making it easy to help you .. db connection? error checking? is employee_id a string or integer? ..

Comment: sorry im new on this. employee_id is a string

Comment: then it should be quoted in the query

Comment: but how? thanks for the code but it dont display the data

Comment: sir this is the result, Could not get data: Champ 'emp000' inconnu dans where clause